# Qr Code show Black preview on second time opening the qr code scanner

Tags: flutter, dart

So the scanner only works well on the first time opening the scanning feature when its asking for permission, it immediately open the camera, but on the second time opening it it only shows black screen, so i need to reverse the camera to the front camera the make it back to the back camera to make it work again :

Heres my code on the scanning screen :

```
class Scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scanner({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScannerState createState() => _ScannerState();
}

class _ScannerState extends State<Scanner> {

  bool _flashOn = false;
  bool _frontCam = false;
  GlobalKey _qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  QRViewController _controller;
  String value;
  Barcode result;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          QRView(
              key: _qrKey,
              overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(borderColor: Color(0xFFE1C884)),
              onQRViewCreated: (QRViewController controller) {
                this._controller = controller;
                controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData){
                  print(scanData);
                  if (mounted) {
                    result = scanData;
                    IdCheckController.text = result.code.toString();
                    _controller.dispose();
                    Navigator.pop(context,scanData);
                  }
                });
              }),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h),
                child: Text(
                  'Scanner',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color:
                          // Colors
                          //     .black,
                          Color(0xFFE1C884),
                      fontFamily: 'Saveur',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20.sp),
                )),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.h),
              child: ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _flashOn = !_flashOn;
                        });
                        _controller.toggleFlash();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(_flashOn
                          ? Icons.flash_on_rounded
                          : Icons.flash_off_rounded),color: Color(0xFFE1C884),),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _frontCam = !_frontCam;
                        });
                        _controller.flipCamera();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(_frontCam
                          ? Icons.camera_front_rounded
                          : Icons.camera_rear_rounded),color: Color(0xFFE1C884),),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),color: Color(0xFFE1C884),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the picture of the black screen :
[image: The Blank preview]

and heres the Terminal Logs :

```
D/ColorViewRootUtil( 8409): nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downX 604 downY 384 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.3235294 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=604.1609, y[0]=384.75952, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2170207146, downTime=2170207146, deviceId=2, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
I/BufferQueue( 8409): [unnamed-8409-34](this:0x79d1751000,id:34,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue core=(8409:hotel)
W/hotel( 8409): type=1400 audit(0.0:8938594): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16455 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c34,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc    ( 8409): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [unnamed-8409-34](this:0x79d1751000,id:34,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) connect(C): consumer=(8409:hotel) controlledByApp=true
E/libc    ( 8409): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [unnamed-8409-34](this:0x79d1751000,id:34,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) setConsumerName: unnamed-8409-34
E/libc    ( 8409): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [SurfaceTexture-0-8409-34](this:0x79d1751000,id:34,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) setConsumerName: SurfaceTexture-0-8409-34
D/Surface ( 8409): lockHardwareCanvas
D/Surface ( 8409): Surface::connect(this=0x79c4b29000,api=1)
I/BufferQueueProducer( 8409): [SurfaceTexture-0-8409-34](this:0x79d1751000,id:34,api:1,p:8409,c:8409) connect(P): api=1 producer=(8409:hotel) producerControlledByApp=true
D/mali_winsys( 8409): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface ( 8409): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x79c4b29000,bufferCount=3)
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [SurfaceTexture-0-8409-34](this:0x79d1751000,id:34,api:1,p:8409,c:8409) setDefaultBufferSize: width=720 height=1600
D/Surface ( 8409): lockHardwareCanvas
D/TextureView( 8409): getHardwareLayer, createNewSurface:true
I/BufferQueue( 8409): [unnamed-8409-35](this:0x79c4f7a000,id:35,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue core=(8409:.hotel)
E/libc    ( 8409): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [unnamed-8409-35](this:0x79c4f7a000,id:35,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) connect(C): consumer=(8409:hotel) controlledByApp=true
E/libc    ( 8409): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [unnamed-8409-35](this:0x79c4f7a000,id:35,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) setConsumerName: unnamed-8409-35
E/libc    ( 8409): Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [SurfaceTexture-0-8409-35](this:0x79c4f7a000,id:35,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) setConsumerName: SurfaceTexture-0-8409-35
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 8409): [SurfaceTexture-0-8409-35](this:0x79c4f7a000,id:35,api:0,p:-1,c:8409) setDefaultBufferSize: width=720 height=1600
D/OpenGLRenderer( 8409): 0x79d19d8da0 setSurfaceTexture: 0x0 to 0x79c4b39400
D/Surface ( 8409): lockHardwareCanvas
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I came across the same issue, and after some time, I found a solution by adding the following code,

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (controller != null && mounted) {
      controller!.pauseCamera();
      controller!.resumeCamera();
    }
    return Scaffold();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    controller?.stopCamera();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

So that every time I re-open the page the controller will be refreshed first and every time I close the page I stop the camera. I hope this can help you...